# Filter access logs on Splunk

Tags: python, bash, apache, perl, splunk

SplunkForwarder is used in order to provide the Apache's access log to Splunk (or was told by DevOps so). AFAIK it's not possible to filter out logs based on given regEx -- the *ISSUE* that I'm trying to solve. Was thinking to add a trigger on Apache that will intercept all requests and send a message to Splunk if the URL pattern of the request is in the whitelist (have found Splunk HTTP Event Collector - never used before - smells like a part of the solution).
Tried to find a proper example of how to use mod_actions module. Unfortunately, didn't find anything that works for me. The Apache's documentation is useless. Not sure whether mod_actions is the only option I have.
Pls, could you tell me how can I execute py/sh/pl or any other script for each request? Likely, DevOps won't allow me to add any exotic (non-standard) module to Apache.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally possible to filter logs based on regex. You'll need an app on indexer to do filtering based on the sourcetype defined in *inputs.conf* on the universal forwarder.

props.conf/transforms.conf combo provided below will keep only the log lines containing strings *Error* or *Warning* while all other messages will be sent to nullqueue (deleted).

$SPLUNK_HOME$/etc/apps/your_app/local/props.conf
$SPLUNK_HOME$/etc/apps/your_app/local/transforms.conf

**props.conf**

```
[your_sourcetype]
TRANSFORMS-set = setnull, setparsing
```

**transforms.conf**

```
# This sends all events to be ignored
[setnull] 
REGEX = .
DEST_KEY = queue
FORMAT = nullQueue

# this says ignore all events, except the ones containing ERROR
[setparsing]
REGEX = Error|Warning
DEST_KEY = queue
FORMAT = indexQueue

[your_sourcetype1]
TRANSFORMS-set = setnull, setparsing

[your_souretype2]
TRANSFORMS-set = setnull, setparsing
```

Comment: If you use a Heavy Forwarder on the Apache Server, rather than a Universal Forwarder, you can put this config there instead of in the indexer. In that way, you don't need to send all the traffic over the network, only to have it removed. Something to consider, based on the volume of logs

Comment: Seems that my company is using Splunk Cloud so I was told that we can't use the filter. Thanks a lot, guys.